# Filter array (with "Date" member) using month

Tags: arrays, swift, date

I have an array "Items" which contains two members: Title and Date

The date is provided from a date picker

```
( newEntry.date = datePicker.date )
```

I'm trying to filter my array based on the month a user chooses, so for example if they choose January it will show all array items with January as the month.

I can filter the array based on the title with:

```
filteredData = items.filter { ($0.name?.lowercased().contains("word"))! }
```

but want another option to filter it based on the date when a month button is pressed. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `DateComponents`:

```
let filteredData = items.filter {
    return Calendar.current.component(.month, from: $0.date) == 1
}
```

Replace the `1` with your selected month.